# Handling orientation changes of other UI components when using android WebView.

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-tablayout

I am using Webview and therefore I let the webviews to take care of any changes in state

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This works fine but the problem is that I also have other UI components (TabLayout). These don't resize on orientation change. I know that I should handle this manually in onConfigurationChanged but I am not sure how to force the TabLayout to redraw. I think the actionbar also needs to be redrawn as it is supposed to be a bit smaller in landscape mode

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (tabs != null) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```